# Цикл должен выпоняться пока не введено n<0

Tags: java

Примитивный таск, но всё же...

Вводится число и выводится такое же количество астерикcов. Если введено отрицательное число, программа останaвливается.

```
public void aster(){
Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.print("Input n:");
  boolean b = true;
  int n = sc.nextInt();
  while(b){
    if (n>0) {
      for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        System.out.print("*");
      }
    } else {
      System.out.println("Program terminated");
      b=false;
    }
  } // while(b)
```

проблема в том, что цикл должен продолжаться пока не введено отрицательное число. Но у меня либо останавливается после первого ввода, либо как в вышеописанном коде, вообще не выполняется.

Comment: А что такое sc.nextInt(); Где обьявляется эта переменная?

Comment: Может это Scanner?  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

Comment: @СергейПряничкин да, я добавил эту строку. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

n должна запрашивать ввод в самом цикле, а у тебя программа опросит один раз n (если делать как ты писал).
Пробуй так, все работает:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class nTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean b = true;
        int n;

        while (b) {
            System.out.print("Input n: ");
            n = sc.nextInt();
            if (n > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                    System.out.println("*");
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Program terminated");
                b = false;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Нет смысла вводить переменну b. Завайте условие завершения цикла. Перед циклом for делать проверку так же бессмысленно, т.к. если n не будет положительным, то ничего не выведется.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

   Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

   int n = 0;

   while (n >=0 ) {
      System.out.print("Input n: ");
      n = sc.nextInt();

      for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
         System.out.println("*");
      }

    }
    System.out.println("Program terminated");
}
```